# Is there a way to keep the bell active on current window (window name ends with !) until cleared?

Tags: tmux

On my local tmux session I connect remotely to another tmux session over ssh.
The only way to have the remote session inform the local tmux session of an event is to ring the terminal bell. In my local tmux window I keep track of the the remote session window name until I see the ! mark for the local session to respond to the event.

The problem I am facing is if the remote session was the active window and the event happened, the bell wont take effect and the window name wont end with !.

Is there a way to change that?
Basically keep the current window name ends with ! on a bell event until it gets cleared?